# Script that centers on a position of a marker/polyline in the kml file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

The following is a script that does geocoding, you can input a city and street and it will look for it. I just need a simple script that can search within positions in the kml file, lets say you input some city and street and if it is as a marker or polyline in the kml file (as a name basically) then screen centers on it. Just that simple script would be welcome. Or you can tell me how to transform this one:

```
    <!--
        var mapa;       
        var dymek;                  
                    var geokoder    = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var rozmiar             = new google.maps.Size(32,32);
        var rozmiar_cien        = new google.maps.Size(59,32);
        var punkt_startowy      = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
        var punkt_zaczepienia   = new google.maps.Point(16,16);
        var ikona               = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon52.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
        var cien                = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon52s.png", rozmiar_cien, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
        var wskaznik            = new google.maps.Marker({icon: ikona, shadow: cien});

        function mapaStart()
        {
            var wspolrzedne = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7671, -122.4206);
            var opcjeMapy = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: wspolrzedne,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            };
            mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), opcjeMapy);
            dymek = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



            geokoder.geocode({address: 'Szczecin, Krzywoustego 23'}, obslugaGeokodowania);


            var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'});
            ctaLayer.setMap(mapa);



            //poniżej marker/tag

            var punkt = new google.maps.LatLng(53.400,14.400); // definiujemy punkt o współrzędnych 53.400,14.400
            var opcjeMarkera =
            {
                position: punkt,
                map: mapa,
                title: 'Pierwszy marker!'
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(opcjeMarkera);



        }


        function skoczDoAdresu(adres)
        {
            wskaznik.setMap(null);
            geokoder.geocode({address: adres}, function(wyniki, status)
            {
                if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    mapa.setCenter(wyniki[0].geometry.location);
                    wskaznik.setPosition(wyniki[0].geometry.location);
                    wskaznik.setMap(mapa);
                    dymek.open(mapa, wskaznik);
                    dymek.setContent('<strong>Poszukiwany adres</strong><br />'+adres);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Nie znalazłem podanego adresu!");
                }
            });
        }

        function obslugaGeokodowania(wyniki, status)
        {

        }

        function skoczdotaga(tag)
        {   
            wskaznik.SetMap(null);

            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    mapa.setCenter(wyniki[0].geometry.location);
                    wskaznik.setPosition(wyniki[0].geometry.location);
                    wskaznik.setMap(mapa);
                    dymek.open(mapa, wskaznik);
                    dymek.setContent('<strong>Poszukiwany adres</strong><br />'+adres);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Brak planów instalacji w tym rejonie");
                }

        }

    -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 doesn't allow access to the feature data in a KML file except in the click event.  To access that data you will need to either:

1. use a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) (which render the KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects)
2. import the KML into [FusionTables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) and access the data by querying the table

[Google CTA KML with sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linkto.html?filename=cta.xml) (uses geoxml3)

[FusionTables example with sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html) (uses google visualization API to access data in fusion table)